# Add plot markers into legend

Tags: legending

Bassicaly I work with the points in data and try to find clusters with different distance functions and show them in the grid.But,how can I add the plot markers `"OpenMarkers"` like with plot legend in the grid plot? Here is what I have done.

```
data = {{-1.1, 2.6}, {3.9, -0.8}, {4.2, -3.7}, {3.3, 3.5}, {3.9, 
    5.2}, {4.1, -4.8}, {3.8, 3.7}, {5.6, 0.1}, {3.1, -5.2}, {-0.9, 
    2.3}, {2.9, 4.1}, {-2.3, 3.9}, {-2.5, 3.}, {2.6, -5.5}, {5.2, 
    1.9}, {-0.7, 1.3}, {0.9, 2.8}, {-1.5, 3.3}, {3.8, 
    1.2}, {2.6, -5.1}, {-0.8, 3.2}, {4.7, 0.7}, {3., 3.}, {3.9, 
    3.6}, {4.5, 1.4}, {4.2, 1.3}, {-1.1, 2.6}, {4.8, 
    2.4}, {3.3, -3.5}, {3.2, -4.6}, {3.3, -4.9}, {3., 3.5}, {0.7, 
    2.1}, {3.2, -4.3}, {-2., 0.5}, {-1.2, 2.}, {-1.6, 1.8}, {-3.5, 
    3.7}, {4.8, 0.2}, {3.3, 2.4}, {-0.1, 2.1}, {-1.3, 2.5}, {4.4, 
    3.9}, {3.5, 0.2}, {0.1, 2.9}, {-1., 1.6}, {-1.4, 4.5}, {3.2, 
    2.5}, {-1.6, 2.4}, {2.6, -5.1}};

Plot1 = ListPlot[
   FindClusters[data, 2, DistanceFunction -> ChebyshevDistance], 
   PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers", PlotLegends -> Automatic];
Plot2 = ListPlot[
   FindClusters[data, 2, 
    DistanceFunction -> SquaredEuclideanDistance], 
   PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers", PlotLegends -> Automatic];
Plot3 = ListPlot[
   FindClusters[data, 2, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance], 
   PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers", PlotLegends -> Automatic];

   Legended[Grid[{{Plot1, Plot2}, {Plot3, None}}], 
 PointLegend[{ColorData[97, 101], 
   ColorData[97, 102]}, {"\[EmptySmallCircle]", "\[EmptyUpTriangle]"}]]
```

I try to use `Legended` and `PointLegended` with the marker symbol but without succes.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nc = 2;
labels = {"cluster 1", "cluster 2"};

plots = ListPlot[FindClusters[data, 2, DistanceFunction -> #], 
        PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers"] & /@ 
    {ChebyshevDistance, SquaredEuclideanDistance, EuclideanDistance};

legend = PointLegend[97, 
    MapThread[Style[##, 16] &, {labels, ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@labels]}], 
    LegendMarkers -> "OpenMarkers"];

Legended[Multicolumn[plots, 2], legend]
```

[image]

or

```
Legended[Grid @ Partition[plots, 2, 2, 1, {}], legend]
```

> same picture

Use

```
nc = 3;
labels = {"cluster 1", "cluster 2",, "cluster 3"};
```

to get

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If the intent is to have a common legend

```
Partition[
  Append[
   ListPlot[
      FindClusters[data, 2,
       DistanceFunction -> #],
      PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers",
      PlotLabel -> #] & /@
    {ChebyshevDistance,
     SquaredEuclideanDistance,
     EuclideanDistance},
   Column[{
     Style["○  Cluster 1", 16, Bold, ColorData[97][1]],
     Style["△  Cluster 2", 16, Bold, 
      ColorData[97][2]]}]], 2] // 
 Grid[#, Spacings -> {Automatic, 3}] &
```

[image]

Using [`Legended`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html)

```
Legended[
 Partition[
   Append[
    ListPlot[
       FindClusters[data, 2,
        DistanceFunction -> #],
       PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers",
       PlotLabel -> #] & /@
     {ChebyshevDistance,
      SquaredEuclideanDistance,
      EuclideanDistance}, ""], 2] //
  Grid[#, Spacings -> {Automatic, 3}] &,
 Placed[
  PointLegend[
   ColorData[97] /@ Range[2],
   StringForm["Cluster ``", #] & /@ Range[2],
   LegendMarkers -> {{"○", 16}, {"△", 16}}],
  {0.85, 0.2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thats the idea. But if I would like to expand the clusters, do I need to insert the markers manually for the legend?